# Обработчик JSON на PHP, ответ на Dart (DIO) POST запрос

Tags: php, json, post, dart

Всем доброго времени суток, буду краток, я новенький в разработке Dart, FLutter
Есть запрос:

```
await dio.post(url, data: currentOrder).then((Response value) async {
    print('sendCurrentOrder: заказ отправлен. \nЗаказ:' + value.toString());
    id = value.data['id'];
    await sendPreferences();
    await getOrderById(id);
  });
```

ну data: currentOrder это определенный массив данных, не суть

Как мне принять POST данные в обработчике PHP, в данный момент используя или не используя json_decode() мне выдает пустой результат, помогите...

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$from_where = json_decode($_POST['from_where']);
$to_where = json_decode($_POST['to_where']);
$price = json_decode($_POST['price']);

$data['success'] = 'Заказ успешный!';

echo json_encode($data);
```

Заранее спасибо, сразу пишу ищу вариант без использования "FormData", этот вариант мне известен давно

Comment: А вы смотрели что приходит в посте json_decode($_POST); ?

Comment: вот именно, что пусто, не могу понять как принимать данные, если те же данные отправляю через FormData, то все ОК, а если посредством Map, то тишина, хотя на старом BackEnd'е все отлично работало, но так получилось что пришлось переписать бэк с нуля, что тут может быть не так, в дебаге вижу что запрос POST уходит нормально, как положено, вопрос почему я не могу его считать?

Comment: json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

Comment: json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); 
Ой спасибо, дорогой) ты мне жизнь спас и время сэкономил)...а то всю жизнь на ajax только работал) а тут flutter подсел